# Ensure text remains visible during webfont load: Doesn't work on added fonts

Tags: magento2, css, fonts, font-family

In our Magento build we have a custom theme that uses Luma as a parent.

After doing an Audit in Chrome we get the message **Ensure text remains visible during webfont load** and it lists the following.

[image]

After following instructions online I add the `font-display: swap;` rule in to **app/design/frontend/THEME/VENDOR/web/css/source/lib/_typography.less** which results to the below.

[image]

The two remaining fonts are ones that I've added inside of **app/design/frontend/THEME/VENDOR/web/css/source/lib/_typography.less**

```
.lib-font-face(
    @family-name:'Hurme Geometric Sans 4',
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/HurmeGeometricSans4/HurmeGeometricSans4SemiBold',
    @font-weight: 600
);

.lib-font-face(
    @family-name:'Hurme Geometric Sans 4 regular',
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/HurmeGeometricSans4/HurmeGeometricSans4-Regular',
    @font-weight: 500
);

.lib-font-face(
    @family-name:'Hurme Geometric Sans 4 light',
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/HurmeGeometricSans4/HurmeGeometricSans4-Light',
    @font-weight: 400
);

.lib-font-face(
    @family-name: 'review-stars',
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/ReviewStars/icomoon',
    @font-weight: normal
);
```

The fonts work but still I get that message. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First correct path file **_typography.less** should be

> app/design/frontend/yourTHEME/VENDOR/web/css/source/_typography.less

you need add font like below

```
.lib-font-face(
   @family-name: 'review-stars',
   @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/ReviewStars/icomoon',
   @font-weight: normal,
   @font-style: normal,
   @font-display: swap
);
```

Comment: Thank you. Since I logged the issue I was able to resolve it by adding it to the correct file like you suggested. Marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: Glad it help you. One more thing you should extend blank theme of magento. It's more stable and seem have better support from magento team than luma. It's up to you

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That's actually my next project to change the parent to Blank instead of Luma.